# DATEDIFF with specific cutoff time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate the number of days between 2 dates and times, but need to cut off at 19:00 rather than 00:00

```
select datediff (dd, '2019-03-14 19:28:00','2019-03-19 10:07:00'),
       datediff (dd, '2019-03-14 19:34:00','2019-03-22 10:20:00'),
       datediff (dd, '2019-03-14 17:13:00','2019-03-25 19:17:00')
```

I would expect to get the results of:

```
'2019-03-14 19:28:00','2019-03-19 10:07:00' = 4, has only passed the 19:00 cut off 4 times.

'2019-03-14 19:34:00','2019-03-22 10:20:00' = 7

'2019-03-14 17:13:00','2019-03-25 19:17:00' = 12
```

SQL calculates these as 5, 8, 11 respectively due to it cutting days off at 00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add five hours:

```
select datediff(day, dateadd(hour, 5, s), dateadd(hour, 5, e))
from (values ('2019-03-14 19:28:00', '2019-03-19 10:07:00'),
             ('2019-03-14 19:34:00','2019-03-22 10:20:00'),
             ('2019-03-14 17:13:00','2019-03-25 19:17:00') 
     ) v(s, e);
```

Or equivalently, subtract 19 hours:

```
select datediff (day, dateadd(hour, -19, s), dateadd(hour, -19, e))
from (values ('2019-03-14 19:28:00', '2019-03-19 10:07:00'),
             ('2019-03-14 19:34:00','2019-03-22 10:20:00'),
             ('2019-03-14 17:13:00','2019-03-25 19:17:00') 
     ) v(s, e);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a DATEDIFF using 19:00 as though it were 00:00, just subtract 19 hours from all the datetime values and do the DATEDIFF on that.